# Android Debugging with Phone with Internet Access

Tags: android

I am playing some Android development and am trying to debug the application via Eclipse on my phone (HTC) with internet access by means of USB tethering because I can't get 3g connection where I am developing and there is no wifi.

I can run the app ok on the phone, but as it requires HTC Sync to be running I am unable to use the internet connection from my computer, is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually android needs the adb to debug devices and afaik adb needs USB connection.

Other ways would be ACRA and BugSense

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to use an emulator: [see here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html)

You can also use [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) on your phone to have access to debugging information directly on the phone, after installing a testversion of your app.

Comment: I normally use an emulator, but the app I am playing with uses the maps api, and the emulator is very slow when the accuracy is set to fine.